# Problem in cross platform (Convert 2 channel wav to mono wav in C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, audio, wav, naudio

below code is only work in Window server.but i want its should also work in Linux server.Convert 2 channel wav to mono wav.please help

```
public static byte[] ConvertWavTo8000Hz16BitMonoWav(byte[] inArray)
{
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(inArray))
    {
        using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(mem))
        {
            using (var converter = 
              WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader))
            {
                using (var upsampler = new WaveFormatConversionStream(new 

                  WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1), converter))
                {
                    byte[] data;
                    using (var m = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        upsampler.CopyTo(m);
                        data = m.ToArray();
                    }
                    using (var m = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        // to create a propper WAV header (44 bytes), 
                        //which begins with RIFF 
                        var w = new WaveFileWriter(m, upsampler.WaveFormat);
                        // append WAV data body
                        w.Write(data,0,data.Length);
                        return m.ToArray();
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can improve the quality of this question by adding information about how you tested and what the results were.

Comment: It's giving error on Linux server "msacm32.dll is not loaded or its dependent  resources" msacm32.dll only present in window server.